# How to get Percentage in two categorical variables in R

Tags: r

Just suppose you have total number of samples as 8. 
Data frame looks like that. All the individuals having Healthscore less than 3 are Healthy and All having health scores greater than 3 are Sick. Status shows their employement status.

```
Status<-(Employed,Unemployed,Student,Student,Employed,Unemployed,Unemployed,Housewife)
Health<-(Healthy,Healthy,Healthy,Sick,Sick,Control,Sick,Sick)

df<-(Status,Health)
level(Health)<-("Healthy,"Sick",Control)
level(Status)<-("Employed","Unemployed","Student","Housewife")
```

I want to see the percentage of Healthy,Sick or Control people belong to each occupation category. I want output like following. (p.s values are just hypothetical in example) like OUT OF ALL EMPLOYED INDIVIDUALS, HOW MANY PERCENTS ARE HEALTHY??

```
                    Healthy      Sick   Control
Employed              10%        2%     1%
Unemployed             5%        1%     1%
Student                6%        3%     1%
Housewife              2%        5%     6%
```

I am using following code. But it just gives me frequencies, NOT PERCENTAGE. I need percentage.

```
tab <- with(df, table(df$Health,df$Status))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `count` the number of individuals for each `Status` and `Health`, `group_by` Status and calculate the percentage. For better visibility we cast the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Status, Health) %>%
  group_by(Status) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Health, values_from = n, 
                     values_fill = list(n = 0))


# Status     Healthy  Sick Control
#  <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 Employed      50    50       0  
#2 Housewife      0   100       0  
#3 Student       50    50       0  
#4 Unemployed    33.3  33.3    33.3
```

---

In base R, we can use `prop.table` along with `table` to get the percentages.

```
prop.table(table(df), 1) * 100
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Status = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("Employed", "Housewife", "Student", "Unemployed"
), class = "factor"), Health = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Control", "Healthy", "Sick"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I want percentage of "Healthy" individuals in each occupation.

Comment: @Aryh  So you can try `table(df$Status, df$Health == 'Healthy')[,'TRUE']` to get number of ''Healthy" individuals for each profession.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BUT i donot want Numbers... I want Percentage.

Comment: Overall percentage? That would be : `table(df$Status, df$Health == 'Healthy')[,'TRUE']/nrow(df) * 100` ?

Comment: Not overall. :( Like out of all the Employed Individuals. (not total)  How many are Healthy?

Comment: @Aryh 1) Make a reproducible example using `dput`. See here how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2) Show the exact expected output for the example shared so that it is clear what are you expecting.

Comment: @Aryh Updated the answer to give you the percentage for each `Status`. Please check if this is what you want.